# How to address a letter to a center within the company?

Tags: communication, business

I want to send a quote letter to the R&D center in a certain company. So here's my question, should I put the name of the center above the company name like this:

> R&D Center
> XYZ Limited.
> #23, abc street...

Or put the company name above the center name like this:

> XYZ Limited.
> R&D Center
> #23, abc street...

Please note, I don't work for that company I work for a different company that wants me to send the quotation to the former company.

Comment: I'd probably do the second one.  It perhaps depends on the country.

Comment: This should moved to legal or English.

Comment: I would also use (Attention) **ATTN: R&D** under the company name.  Most RMAs (simplest example) are addressed in this way (MSI Manufacturing Plant 5//ATTB: RMA Department 5//[Address Here])

Answer (score 6):

*It doesn't matter* - no sane company is going to view a quote any differently because of the order you put two lines in the address. Just send the quote and move on with your life to something that will actually make a difference.

Answer (score 5):

A quote needs to go to the buyer for that R&D center. Nobody else can act on it. So, find out the name of the buyer and address the quote to that person. If that person has not requested the quote, the probability of the quote being acted upon is very low.

If you are the sales person for your company, I would strongly recommend making contact with the buyer first. It often takes multiple contacts before someone will buy and a better way is to call, send quote, and do a follow up call. That gives you the first three contacts of the needed 5-10 contacts before a sale happens.

If you are not the sales person for your company, this is WAY out of your skills and responsibilities. Go talk to the sales person and get them involved.